# Evaluate the double integral using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Using polar coordinates evaluate the double integral of $\sin(x^2 + y^2) \mathrm{d}A$,

where the region is $4 \le  x^2 + y^2 \le 64$.

I know that we have to find the range of angle and the range of $r$. Should the angle be between $0$ and $2\pi$ and the $r$ between $2$ and $8$? And then how do I set up the integral?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  Exactly like you'd expect: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_2^8 \sin(r^2)r\ \textrm{d}r\textrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: Why is it that just r^2 inside of sin ?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2$.$\ $

Comment: Am getting a negative number. is that ok?

Comment: Yes.  It should be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Your question "how do I set up the integral?" is probably the most frequently asked question in my multivariable calculus course.

A double integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\displaystyle \iint_D f(x,y)dA$, has three pieces of data: the region of integration $D$, the function $f(x,y)$, and the area differential $dA$. Setting up the integral in polar coordinates requires you to transform/convert all three things: $dA \to r dr d\theta$, $f(x,y) \to f(r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$, and describing $D$ in polar coordinates.

A nice shortcut is that for polar coordinates $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ the expression $x^2 + y^2$ always transforms to $r^2$, a consequence of the Pythagorean identity.